# Drop-down menu in CSS appears under page content

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have done hours and hours of research on this issue but can't get it to work! I finally got my CSS menu looking exactly how I want it to - yay!  But now it drops down under the other content on the page, and I can't figure out how to get it to come up on top. I have adjusted the positioning as many people mentioned, and set the z-index settings all the way up to 2000, with no effect.  What am I doing wrong??  Using Firefox - current version.

Here is the CSS code (and no, I don't have a link to show example, as the site isn't published yet)

```
    #cssmenu:before, #cssmenu:after, #cssmenu > ul:before, #cssmenu > ul:after {

    content: '';
    display: table;

}


#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu > ul:after {

    clear: both;

}
#cssmenu
{
    zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul
{
    background: #00305f;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#cssmenu > ul li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

}

#cssmenu > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a
{
    padding: 20px 25px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, Serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(151, 99, 33, .43);
    line-height: 18px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a
{
    background: #5783af;

}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span
{
    line-height: 18px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a
{
    background: #5783af;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active
{
    background: #5783af;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul
{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    background: #00305f;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .35s .2s ease-in-out;
}

#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul
{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
    color: #5783af;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 64px;
    left: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    background: transparent;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li a
{
    padding: 12px 20px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, Serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 175px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(151, 99, 33, .43);
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover
{
    border-left: 4px solid #055988;
    background: #5783af;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active
{
    background: #5783af;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='home.html'><span>Home</span></a>
  <ul>
         <li><a href='resources.html'><span>Resources</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='products.html'><span>Products</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='health-wellness.html'><span>Health & Wellness</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='cooking-from-scratch.html'><span>Cooking From Scratch</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='sustainable-gardening.html'><span>Sustainable Gardening</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='csa.html'><span>Community Supported Agriculture</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='fun-ways-to-exercise.html'><span>Fun Ways to Exercise</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='pain-relief.html'><span>Natural Relief for Chronic Pain</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='toxic-load.html'><span>Reducing Your Toxic 

Load</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='relationships.html'><span>Relationships</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='wealth.html'><span>Wealth</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='spirituality.html'><span>Spirituality</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help to see the structure of your HTML, too. You can use a tool like http://jsfiddle.net to post your (excerpted) CSS and HTML in context, even though your site's not live.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
    #cssmenu
{
    zoom: 1;
z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: @medmunds - Thanks - sorry - here is HTML - I added it at bottom of the original post above. I tried running it in jsfiddle - thanks for the suggestion, and it seemed to work fine, but doesn't work on my site. :-(

Comment: Example - looks fine here, but on my site with other content, it drops down behind the other content: http://jsfiddle.net/R3KcV/embedded/result/